# How to show that there exist a m such that $a_0I+a_1T+\dots+a_mT^m=0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Prove that for any transformation $T:V\rightarrow V$ , there exist a m and $a_0$,$a_1$,....,$a_m$ not all zero such that $a_0I+a_1T+\dots+a_mT^m=0$.

Honestly, I don't understand this question. And didn't understand how to begin. Why there has to be such m?. Its clearly indicate such an $m$ exists for which $\{I,T,......,T^m\}$ is linearly dependent. Is there anything special since the domain and codomain of T are the same?. Please I need your help. Thank you.

Note that V is finite dimensional.

Comment: As stated, this statement is false. Is V known to be finite-dimensional?

Comment: Yes V is known to be finite dimensional

Comment: Then what do you know about the space of all linear maps $V\rightarrow V$?

Comment: If dimension of V is n then the space of all linear maps V$\rightarrow$V is isomorphic to the n×n matrices.

Comment: So in particular it is finite dimensional. What is the maximum number of linearly-independent vectors in a finite dimensional vector space?

Comment: It is same as its dimension. So I have to take m such that it will be greater than the dimension  of the vector space.and then it will be linearly dependent?. Am I right?.

Comment: Yes, that's the idea.

Comment: Another way to see it is to check $T$'s characteristic polynomial, which by Cayley-Hamilton theorem is $T$'s annihilating polynomial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over a field $\mathbb{F}$, with a basis $\{ b_1,b_2,\cdots,b_m\}$. If $T$ is a linear transformation on $V$, then $T$ is completely determined by the unique constants $\{ a_{r,s} \}$, for $1 \le r,s \le m$ such that
$$
           T(b_1) = a_{1,1}b_1+a_{1,2}b_2+\cdots+a_{1,m}b_m \\
           T(b_2) = a_{2,1}b_1+a_{2,2}b_2+\cdots+a_{2,m}b_m  \\
            \vdots \\
           T(b_m) = a_{m,1}b_1+a_{m,2}b_2+\cdots+a_{m,m}b_m.
$$
So $T$ is represented by an $m\times m$ matrix over $\mathbb{F}$. The set of $m\times m$ matrices over $\mathbb{F}$ is an $m^2$ dimensional vector space. Therefore $\{ I,T,T^2,\cdots,T^{m\times m}\}$ is a linearly-depenedent set of matrices, which gives constants $\alpha_0,\alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_m$ that are not all $0$ such that
$$
                         \alpha_0 I + \alpha_1 T + \cdots + \alpha_m T^{m^2} = 0.
$$